# Computing and plotting the cantor function

Tags: r, if-statement, math, vectorization

I wanted to implement the cantor function in R and plot it. I only know Python and Java so R is new for me.
The cantor function is defined as:

---

Let f0(x) = x.

Then, for every integer n ≥ 0, the next function fn+1(x) will be defined in terms of fn(x) as follows:

Let fn+1(x) = 1/2 × fn(3x),  when 0 ≤ x ≤ 1/3 ;

Let fn+1(x) = 1/2,  when 1/3 ≤ x ≤ 2/3 ;

Let fn+1(x) = 1/2 + 1/2 × fn(3 x − 2),  when 2/3 ≤ x ≤ 1.

---

This is my code:

```
cantor <- function(x,n){
  if (n==0){
    return(x)
  }else{
    if(0 <= x & x <= 1/3){
      return(1/2*cantor(3*x,n-1))
  }else if(1/3 < x & x < 2/3){
    return(1/2)
  }else{
    return(1/2+1/2*cantor(3*x-2,n-1))
  }
  }
}
```

which works well as long as it has an single input.
But if I try to plot it over
`x=seq(0,1,0.01)`
it does not work because my conditions are for single inputs but R gives the whole vector x to my function.

Is there a way to have only an single input over an vector or how do I rewrite my code so it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sapply` or a `for` loop to make this work for vectors.

```
x=seq(0,1,0.01)
y <- sapply(x, cantor, n = 3)
```

With `for` loop :

```
y <- numeric(length(x))
for(i in seq_along(y)) {
  y[i] <- cantor(x[i], 3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply`

```
x <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)
y <- unlist(lapply(x, cantor, n = 3))
```